# jetty: store request-specific information

Tags: java, android, jakarta-ee, jersey

I am creating some sort of RESTful API with basic auth. To handle the auth information I added a custom ContainerRequestFilter. This works quite good, but I want to set global information like the "username" of the caller. How can I set global/request-specific information or properties and get them within a "Controller" method?

```
//some filter
public class AuthFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter{

    //...

    @Override
    public void filter( ContainerRequestContext requestContext ) throws IOException {
        requestContext.setProperty("username", "someusername");
    }


    //...

}

//example "route-handler"
@GET 
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<Event> getEvents() {
    //HOW to get the username property?!
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inject `HttpServletRequest` into your controller and use `HttpServletRequest.getAttribute` to retrieve the values you set in `ContainerRequestContext.setProperty`.

```
@GET 
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<Event> getEvents(@Context HttpServletRequest req) {
    String username = (String) req.getAttribute("username");  
    ...
}
```

I've used that on Glassfish/Jersey and it works fine so it should work in your environment.

Comment: I always receive an 'Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest' error message. I added servlet-api dependency to my pom, without change.

Comment: According to the documentation I've looked at the class is part of Jetty. What version are you using? Any chance you could post the log?

Comment: I found the failure: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25338377/java-ee-class-not-found-despite-valid-import/25338542#25338542

Comment: Within my filter I call `requestContext.setProperty("username", phone_username);`, but within the Controller `(Long) request.getAttribute("username");` is null. What's wrong?